# install4j: Redirecting stdout to install4j startup scripts

Tags: java, install4j

Are the install4j launchers capable of redirecting the output to the screen, rather than just invoking the java command and closing. Our software has several dependencies that are initialized to create our daemon and each binary is dependent on one another, and order of initialization is critical.

Right now, we tail into our log files to validate the successful execution of each binary but this is slightly tedious. I've incorporated a start-all script but our CTO insist that we stick to install4j startup scripts to ensure consistency between our software and the install4j launchers so that when we are ready for release, no new bugs arise.

Thank you,

Chris

Comment: Use a logging framework and configure the logging framework to log to the  console when asked to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install4j launchers redirect stdout or stderr output to files if you configure this on the *Executable info->Redirection* step of the launcher wizard. If you don't configure redirection, the output will be shown on the console for console launchers. For GUI launchers, no output can be shown on Windows and Mac OS X, because the process does not have a connection to a terminal.

So you need an additional console launcher for this case that has no configured redirection.